# Show ng-model length using controllerAs

Tags: angularjs

I using controllerAs, stroring text in ng-model and next save in database and I have one problem because I can't view `ng-model` `length`. How show `ng-model="seeMore.comment"` length?

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="text-area-comment" name="comment" ng-model="seeMore.comment" ng-minLength="10" required></textarea>  
<ul ng-show="(!AddCommentForm.comment.$pristine && AddCommentForm.comment.$error.minlength)" class="help-block">
    <li>{{seeMore.comment.length}} to go.. </li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: please elaborate your query

Comment: I would show how many characters is added in textarea, and I think good solution is use ng-model length

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can access 'seeMore.comment' and find the length using length function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below demo
In this demo my model name is **myText**, so to display length I am using `myText.length`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Hello world';
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div>{{title}}</div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="myText" /> Length:{{myText.length}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an DOM like this.. where you have the `ctrl as vm` part
so I modified part of your code you posted with the pre `vm`. So now you can
access to the model of the controller alias corresponding.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
   <form name="vm.AddCommentForm.comment">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="text-area-comment" name="comment" ng-model="vm.seeMore.comment" ng-minLength="10" required></textarea>  
        <ul ng-show="(!vm.AddCommentForm.comment.$pristine && 
    vm.AddCommentForm.comment.$error.minlength)" class="help-block">
        <li>{{vm.seeMore.comment.length}} to go.. </li>   
    </ul>
   </form>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
     var vm = this;         
     vm.seeMore = {comment:''};
});
```